# Edit "Create Account" registration form for Magento Store

Tags: php, forms, magento, registration, account

I would like to edit the required fields when a customers creates a new account with my store. Currently the form requires the customer to enter his First Name, Last Name, Email and Password. I want to disable First Name and Last Name from being required, maybe even not showing those fields. I just interested on the Email and maybe a username, and of course the password.

I am currently using Magento version 1.7

Comment: I changed the required status in the database, from 1 to 0. But that didn't work. I was reading some similar post and I was analyzing the codes of different files but I wasn't sure what modifications to make. Hence I made this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the extension ([Fast Registration](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/19173/s/fast-registration-6987/)) which allow disable First Name, Last Name and Email fields.

After you changed required status in the database you need to override `AccountController.php` (`app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`). 
In `createPostAction()` you need to comment this lines:

```
$customerErrors = $customer->validate();
if (is_array($customerErrors)) {
    $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
}
```